# Visually, why is the 2-sphere $S^2$ not contractible?

Tags: general-topology

In topology, can someone please describe why the sphere $S^2$ is not contactable? Surely it can just 'shrink' to a point?

Comment: But imagine trying to shrink $S^2$ to a point while trying to stay inside the sphere itself. Of course you can let it shrink to a point if you let it move through $\mathbb{R}^3$. But the homotopy must be between the identity and a constant map and lie inside the sphere for all $t$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue with your logic is that you must shrink your space **while** staying within your original space. For example, your idea is roughly to consider the balls of radius $t$ around $0$ and let $t\to 0$. Now, the definition of the homotopy is a map $H:[0,1]\times S^2\to S^2$--your spaces (maps rigorously) don't lie on (map into) $S^2$ after $t=1$.

Comment: What you mean 'after $t=1'$? Do you mean $t$ can be more than $1$?